# redis restart not using conf file setting

Tags: redis

Recently I found that my redis service auto-restart by itself and not using the redis.conf file configuration.

Any suggestion what is the default location should I place the redis.conf file so that the conf file is effective when the service auto-restart, thanks in advance

Comment: anyone has idea??

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `INFO` command to see where is Redis looking for `redis.conf` file.

[Redis INFO command documentation](https://redis.io/commands/info/)

> config_file: The path to the config file

Comment: thanks for the answer! but when i check the info, i saw null for config_file para :(